# Norfolk Island Pine

Tags: diseases, watering, pines, browning

My Norfolk Island pine is dying, I normally give it 3/4 solo cup of water every two weeks, but it got over watered I believe (two weeks straight instead of skipping)
Please advise. Is there any hope of it bouncing back?

[image]

Comment: Are there drainage holes in the pot?

Answer (score 1):

If no drainage holes in the pot, repot to one (preferably a bit larger) that has drainage holes. That's the only way I could see it being that much affected by the described overwatering.

I had one in college, (in a pot with holes) and I certainly was not all that fussy about watering it, and it survived many years, but eventually got to the annoying point where it dropped all the lower limbs (as they do - maintaining the "miniature pyramidal form" is a lot of work, and eventually fails, IME) so it was just a bare trunk with a few layers of branches up top.